# Scanner Stop working

Tags: drivers, usb, scanner

I am on ubuntu 18. I have used scanner before using simplescan. But it is not working now giving "Faild to scan Unable to connent to scanner". I don't understand the drivers in linux but I have tried all the online  solutions with no help.

The printer is visible in simplescan and all softwares I have used. I have also tried xsane, gimp and gscan2pdf

running `scanimage -L` gives

```
scanimage -L
#device `hpaio:/usb/Deskjet_F2200_series?serial=CN83R4T4TF0534' is a Hewlett-Packard #Deskjet_F2200_series all-in-one
```

Also I have tried this command

```
sudo sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x0bda [Generic], product=0x0139 [USB2.0-CRW]) at libusb:001:005
found USB scanner (vendor=0x03f0 [HP], product=0x2404 [Deskjet F2200 series]) at libusb:001:008
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports

  # can't be detected by this program.
```